# Conditional execution of elisp code based on value of environment variable

Tags: emacs, terminal, elisp

In my `.emacs` config file I have a following entry:

```
(custom-set-variables
  (custom-set-faces
    '(font-lock-comment-face ((((class color)
                                (min-colors 8)
                                (background dark))
                                (:foreground "red"))))))
```

This fixes the font color when `TERM` environment variable is set to `screen`, but breaks it when `TERM` is set to `xterm`. Is there a way to read value of `TERM` variable and execute that code only if `TERM`'s value is `screen`? I found [this questin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549978/elisp-conditional-based-on-hostname)  slightly helpful, but still I don't know how to read values of environment variables in elisp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(when (string= (getenv "TERM") "screen")
    .... your code
)
```

Answer (score 7):

First I will answer what you asked, below I will answer the question you really should have asked ;)

I get the value of an environment variable you use the function `getenv`. For example:

```
(getenv "TERM")   ->  "xterm-color"
```

However, this is a relatively clumsy way to check if your Emacs run in the terminal. Instead you can use the following:

```
(display-graphic-p &optional DISPLAY)

Return non-nil if DISPLAY is a graphic display.
Graphical displays are those which are capable of displaying several
frames and several different fonts at once.  This is true for displays
that use a window system such as X, and false for text-only terminals.
DISPLAY can be a display name, a frame, or nil (meaning the selected
frame's display).
```

An older, deprecated, version is to check the variable `window-system`.

Comment: I didn't make myself clear - I always run Emacs in terminal. It's just that my terminal emulator sets TERM="xterm", while Tmux (when run from the very same terminal) sets TERM="screen".

Comment: In that case, getenv, is the way to go.